# HTML variable and text value transfer to PHP/javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

So this is what i have in html:

```
    <p><br><form name="edit" method="post">
        <div><select name="Edi" id ="Edi" >
        <option selected="selected">Select</option>
        <option value="1.php">Apple</option>
        <option value="1.php">Bannana</option>
        <option value="2.php">Carrot</option>
        </select>
            <input onclick="return Edit();" type="submit" value="Edit"/></div>
    </form>
```

here is the corresponding javascript:

```
function Edit(){
    if(document.forms['edit'].Edi.value == "Select")
        {
            alert("Please Select Edit Field");
            return false;
        }
    else
    {
        window.open(Edi.options[Edi.selectedIndex].value);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Here is my problem. As you can see both my option Apple, and Bannana open the same php page. I want that. But i also want a variable in PHP that can store Apple/Bannana depending which was chosen in dropdown.
I tried this in PHP and it did not work.

```
 $Table = $_POST['Edi'];
```

I know i can create a different PHP page for Apple(1.php) and Bannana(3.php).  But in my program creating a page will just be duplicated code. (Apple and bannana just decide which table to store in). Also, i might be adding more options in the future, so i dont want to keep copying code.

What i came up with is putting the variable in javascript, but then tranfering to PHP is not possible. So I decided with creating extra layer rather than creating copied pages. (1 selected-shows apple, bananna) (2 selected-shows carrot). I can do this.

But is this the most efficient way of doing this?

Comment: It depends on the context. You might just add Apple/Banana in GET parameter. (Simplest way to do it but maybe not most efficient, secure, good looking, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PHP's [`$_GET`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) array to access URL parameters.

For example:

```
<option value="1.php?table=apple">Apple</option>
<option value="1.php?table=banana">Banana</option>
```

And your PHP:

```
$table = $_GET['table'];
```

If the variable could be missing, you can provide a default value by using PHP's [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary):

```
$table = isset($_GET['table']) ? $_GET['table'] : 'apple';
```

Comment: What i was looking for. Works like a charm!